# Is it possible to use ionic Capacitor with a Django application?

Tags: django, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a Django application that loads a React app on a child page. Is it possible to use the ionic Capacitor with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Ionic allows you to build iOS, Android and web apps with a single codebase, and Capacitor enables access between your application and the device the application is running on. Therefore, you can build either a web or mobile application that consumes your Django APIs, similar to what your React app is currently doing. You can learn more at https://capacitor.ionicframework.com.